# Which one is correct to say 3 in 1 celebration or 3 in 1 celebrations

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, noun-phrases

I'm making one tarpaulin for my mom, dad and brother and we don’t know  which one is correct to say:

- three-in-one celebrations
- a three-in-one celebration

In other words, is *three-in-one celebration(s)* a singular or plural noun phrase?

(We'll write the banner using digits *(a) 3 in 1 celebration(s)*).

Comment: Hello Maria. Welcome to English Stack Exchange. If you have any questions, please consult the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help). As for your question, proofreading requests are strictly disallowed and must therefore be removed from English Stack Exchange.  However, [many websites do offer proofreading services, quite a few of which are free to use](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+proofreading+service), and all of which are more than adequate for your needs.

Comment: A tarpaulin is a kind of waterproof sheet of material, originally cloth such as canvas coated with tar, nowadays it can be some kind of flexible plastic. What has that to do with a celebration?

Comment: @VTH This kind of question is most specifically allowed. It is one which has identified the specific concern of the author. In this case it is doubly allowed because it is about grammar.

Comment: What do you mean by "a 3 in 1 celebration"? Can you explain what you want to say?  Usually this type of structure is used in statistics but the first number is smaller, e.g "3 in 5 marriages end in divorce."

Comment: @Araucaria Point taken. OP was just being too ambiguous and I seem to have misinterpret this as a proofreading request, somehow.

Comment: @Mari-LouA OP seems to imply that the celebration was meant for her mom, dad and brother, hence **three-in-one**.

Comment: @VTH why is the sister/daughter excluded from the celebration? Unless the brother shares the same birthday with one or both parents, or something similar. I get the "three/four [functions] in one" printer, but this formula I don't.

Comment: @Araucaria you have talked to the OP and edited the question, you also know that the OP wants to use digits instead of words. Can you say "why" the OP wants to write (a) 3-in-1 celebration, or (a) 3 in 1 celebration?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Is this going to be one of those long comment thingies where you ending up asking me to delete my comments? :-)

Comment: @Araucaria no, it won't be. I'll just cast my vote to close because it's unclear :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA It seems pretty clear to me. The OP asked in the title which was correct: "3 in 1 celebration" or "3 in 1 celebration**s**". They then asked in the body of the question, in which they explain and elaborate, " Is the celebration with **a** or without **a**?" This is identical to asking whether the compound noun there is singular or necessarily plural. (The OP most certainly wasn't asking what the meaning of *3 in 1 celebration* is or whether it was apposite or not.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA The edits were done because OP is new here, and their question was risking getting  close votes for appearing to be proof-reading. Not nice for your first visit, especialy if your concern was on-topic.

Comment: @Araucaria the OP has given an explanation in a comment to Lawrence's answer.

Answer (score 5):

The term three-in-one is a bit of a red herring. You’d need *celebration* to agree with the specified number of such celebrations.

- The tarpaulin was made for **a** 3-in-1 **celebration** (singular agreement).
- The tarpaulin was made for **a** 3-in-2 **celebration** (singular agreement).
- The tarpaulin was made for **five** 3-in-1 **celebrations** (plural agreement).

Comment: Thanks for all ur answer but ur not getting my point. It’s not about the tarpaulin. It’s about the corrrect grammar of the sentence 3 in 1 celebration or celebrations. Which means I have 3 celebrants but in one celebration.

Comment: "I have 3 celebrants but in **one celebration**" You answered your own question.

Comment: @SolnikowskiMaria The tarpaulin was just a detail. Look at the parts in bold. If you have *one* celebration (whether "3-in-1" or "anniversary" or "4-in-2" or whatever), it takes singular agreement. If you have multiple celebrations (of whatever kind), it takes plural agreement.

Comment: @SolnikowskiMaria please edit your question and add the necessary clarifications in *your* question.

Answer (score 3):

We would write or say "a three-in-one celebration". If a number (more than one) of items are combined into one thing, then that thing is treated as a singular item. I have combined garlic, lemon and dill into a three-in-one sauce.

> Scientists have developed a three-in-one blood test.
>
> A three-in-one maternity bag: handbag, removable tote, and a changing
>   mat in one.
>
> Our male grooming three in one shampoo is suitable for all hair types
>   and it not only cleans but it conditions hair, face and body.

Most style guides advise writing smaller numbers (e.g. less than 11) as words, thus three-in-one and not 3-in-1.

Comment: ["4-in-1 printer"](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=Wq2LW8SIHYmxkwXF5paoDQ&q=%224-in-1+printer%22&oq=%224-in-1+printer%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1l10.17401.20207.0.20511.2.2.0.0.0.0.146.260.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.259...0i22i30k1.0.jGPS6GaoTHQ) but words: ["all in one printer"](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=ya2LW_HsEYuO0gLjxYTIAg&q=%22all+in+one+printer%22&oq=%22all+in+one+printer%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1l2j0i67k1j0l3j0i7i30k1l2j0i67k1j0.6329.14662.0.16377.8.8.0.0.0.0.137.976.0j8.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.8.972...0i7i5i30k1j0i30k1j0i5i30k1j0i13k1.0.JHEHoikBvoE)